# Create a 2d transformation matrix with rotation origin

Tags: canvas, matrix, vector, affinetransform, matrix-transform

I'm trying to get my 2d transformation matrix with a pivot to work in my html canvas. Everything works fine when I use a pivot of 0,0, but as soon as I want to add a rotation origin to the yellow shape it doesn't work as I would like it to.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKxAb.jpg

The yellow shape should have its center at the same position as the red shape. The pivot's position should be relative to the shape, not to the world. I had the solution to this problem a few years back, but I can't remember the exact calculation. I know I'm missing something for tx and ty.

Any ideas?

```
drawRectangle(context, 45, new Vector2(50, 50), new Vector2(1, 1), new Vector2(50, 50), 'yellow');
drawRectangle(context, 0, new Vector2(50, 50), new Vector2(1, 1), new Vector2(0, 0), 'red');
void drawRectangle(CanvasRenderingContext2D context, num rotation, Vector2 position, Vector2 scale, Vector2 pivot, String color) {
    Matrix3 m = new Matrix3.Identity();
    num rad = toRadians(rotation);
    num sr = sin(rad);
    num cr = cos(rad);
    m.a = cr * scale.x;
    m.b = sr * scale.x;
    m.c = -sr * scale.y;
    m.d = cr * scale.y;
    m.tx = position.x - (pivot.x * m.a + pivot.y * m.c);
    m.ty = position.y - (pivot.x * m.b + pivot.y * m.d);
    context.setTransform(m.a, m.b, m.c, m.d, m.tx, m.ty);
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    context.fillStyle = color;
    context.globalAlpha = 0.5;
    context.fill();
    context.closePath();
    context.resetTransform();
}
```

Comment: 1) Translate shape so that the center of rotation is at the origin. 2) Rotate the shape. 3) Translate the shape back to its original position. You can do all 3 in one step by multiplying the three transformation matrices together in that order. I'm a bit rusty, but I'm 95% sure that's right.

Comment: @jpmc26: You're close! 1) translate to the desired rotation point, 2) rotate to the desired angle, 3) translate by -shapeWidth/2, -shapeHeight/2, 4) draw the shape as if its not in transformed space, 5) untransform: setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0). Note that transforms don't move shapes, they actually move the canvas origin and rotate the canvas coordinate system. Also to BigBen: canvas will buffer its transformations & drawings until a stroke or fill command is issued so shadowing the transformation matrix with your own matrix is not needed for performance--although it is useful in code logic.